# How to represent object with holes

Tags: image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

To represent objects in image we can use boundary based techniques like chain codes. But they cannot be used to represent objects as given below,
[image]

Can anyone please tell me a technique to represent this?

Answer (score 0):

Chain codes could still be used if the orientation of the ring is taken into account: for instance a clockwise ring means outer boundary, an anticlockwise one means inner boundary (hole boundary). The signed area of the ring can be used to find its orientation.

If the objects have multiple layers of holes (holes with islands, islands which also have holes, etc...), then some additional encoding convention or marker scheme is needed to find on which layer the next ring to be decoded is.